# Passing Credentials as parameter to GIT configuration in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

Our objective  is to define a  Jenkins template job where all information would be parameterized, We will collect input from the user all  the  way  from GIT URL, GIT credentials (as a  credentials  parameter), Type of build tool etc and would create a JOB pipeline in Jenkins  based on the various inputs.

Can some one let  me know how to pass a parameter in the  credentials section of GIT (under Source code  management section) so that  what  ever  input given by the user  can be updated  in the new job which is  getting created

Comment: what are you using to create those jobs?

Comment: you can check if inbuilt git plugin has an API to add git credentials or you can use third party plugin for that

Comment: I'm using JOB generator plugin to create those jobs

Comment: I have same demand, How did you solve?Thanks.